# How to pass results calculated in an external class to other classes and constantly update the values?

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating code in Python. The following code is created using a GUI library called Kivy. It's code that automatically calculates and changes the font size when the UI size changes.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text.markup import MarkupLabel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            ResizableLabel:
                text: "test1"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test2"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test3"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test4"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test5"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test6"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "test7"
                font_size: root.resized_font_size
""")

class ResizableLabel(Label):
    markup = True

    def on_text(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.adjust_font_size()

    def on_size(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.adjust_font_size()

    def adjust_font_size(self):
        font_size = self.font_size
        lbl_available_height = self.height*0.9
        lbl_available_width = self.width*0.6
    
        while True:
            lbl = MarkupLabel(font_name=self.font_name, font_size=font_size, text=self.text)
            lbl.refresh()

            if font_size > lbl_available_height:
                font_size = lbl_available_height
            elif lbl.content_width > lbl_available_width or \
                lbl.content_height > lbl_available_height:
                font_size *= 0.95
            else:
                break
        
        while True:
            lbl = MarkupLabel(font_name=self.font_name, font_size=font_size, text=self.text)
            lbl.refresh()
            if lbl.content_width * 1.1 < lbl_available_width and \
                lbl.content_height * 1.1 < lbl_available_height:
                font_size *= 1.05
            else:
                break
        
        self.font_size = font_size

class TestWidget(Widget):
    resized_font_size = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.resized_font_size = 22

    def printTest(self):
        print("printTest")

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In this code, within the `ResizableLabel` class, the font size is calculated to fit the GUI size. However, I am applying the values obtained from `ResizableLabel` only to the topmost text in the GUI.

This is because performing resizing calculations for all fonts would result in a high computational load.

I want to pass the values calculated for the top font to the other fonts as well. For the second font onwards, I am passing the value using a variable called '`resized_font_size`.'

How can I always pass the values calculated within the `ResizableLabel` class to the '`resized_font_size`' variable in the `TestWidget` class?"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding the following code at the end of your `adjust_font_size()` method:

```
    testwidget = App.get_running_app().root
    if testwidget:
        testwidget.resized_font_size = font_size
```

The test is required because the `Testwidget` instance is created before the `root` of the `App` is assigned.

Another approach is to modify your `kv` (instead of modifying your code) as below:

```
<TestWidget>:
    resized_font_size: rsl.font_size  # assign the desired font size
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            ResizableLabel:
                id: rsl  # Added id 
                text: "test1"
```

The rest of the `kv` is unchanged.